# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context with AES while using Decryption

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

Type of expression is ambiguous without more context with AES while using Decryption my xcode  version 9.4 and swift version is 4.1

```
extension String {
    func aesDecrypt(key: String, iv: String) -> String {
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: self)!
        do{
            let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding : .pkcs7() ).decrypt([UInt8](data))
            let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
            return String(bytes: decryptedData.bytes, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Could not decrypt"
        }
        catch {
            print("error in aes")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it working by replacing

```
let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding : .pkcs7() ).decrypt([UInt8](data))
```

with

```
let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, blockMode: CBC(iv: iv), padding: .pkcs7).decrypt([UInt8](data))
```

But there is another changes which needs to be done like you need to change argument type like shown below:

```
func aesDecrypt(key: [UInt8], iv: [UInt8]) -> String {
```

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94430232884226599486) demo project for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot

`import CryptoSwift`